# "While" as a non-temporal adverb

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, adverbs

Is it correct in formal writing to use *while* as a non-temporal adverb?
For instance

> Phenomenon A is generated by XXX, **while** phenomenon B is generated by YYY

Should I rather use :

> Phenomenon A is generated by XXX, **but/and** phenomenon B is generated by YYY

Note that I do not want to imply that A and B are happening at the same time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is perfectly correct and I believe more adapted in cases where there is a slight difference between the two compared entities.

For instance, you would use *but* when there is an idea of opposition.

> *Phenomenon A is assumed to be generated by XXX, **but** this is still under discussion*.

In contrast, you would use *while* when the opposition is compounded with some similarities.
In that case the use of *while* is a smarter way to emphasise a smaller difference within a broader background within which the two compared entities bear some similarities.

> *Phenomenon A is generated by XXX, **while** phenomenon B is [**instead**] generated by YYY*.

Another way of achieving a similar effect is to use **whereas** or **in contrast...**.

It's also probably worth noting that in this case ***while*** is not an adverb any more but a coordinating conjunction.

Answer (score 2):

Choice of words in the English Language is, in most cases, a matter of opinion and personal preference. There is no single *correct* word for any given situation. Neither can one confidently say whether one word is arguably better than another. However keeping in regard **formal writing**, there are often a number of words which you should refrain from using and vice versa. But in this case, I think both conditions are valid and will be accepted.

If , however, you want my opinion, I think the first example is more preferable. Using **while** (in my opinion) makes the tone of the sentence slightly more formal and literary. Since I have often seen experienced authors and conversationalists use **while** instead of **and/but**, I advise you to do the same.

Comment: *"There is no _correct_ word for any given situation."*  So can I start referring to the stranded stuff on the top of my head as "albacore"?  Or, put a different way, sentence formal is advise not purple legerdemain verily the correct seen  fourscore we order "albacore"?

Comment: @wfaulk: I think what he/she meant was *there is not just _one_ correct word for each situation*. Or, at least, that is how I interpreted it. Of course this does not imply that there are no wrong words!

Comment: @wfaulk What I meant was that there is no single correct word for any given situation. I didn't say there are no INCORRECT words.

Comment: @IntermediateHacker: I know.  Was joke.